# Power point VBA macro: max length and execute through script

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

BACKGROUND: We do automated data analysis on huge amount of data and need to automate the report generation. My current solution is having a python script that parse a VB script that generates the PPT report. I have 2 specific problems that I can't find answers on:

PROBLEMS:

1. So far, the VB script is saved as a .txt file. I would then manually copy the contents, paste it on MS PowerPoint VB interface, and run it. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? E.g. (1) is there a specific file extension which is recognized by Windows to be executed as ppt macro, so my users can double click the icon and it just executes the PPT? (2) or is there a way to use python to invoke PPT to run the macro? I can then just save the actual presentation.
2. I found that the manual copy-paste approach above returns an error if the macro length is roughly > 1000 lines (this is a huge amount of data!). I can't find the exact macro size limit. What is the maximum length for this kind of PPT macro? Is there any way to work around this limitation in an elegant way? My current workaround is to parse multiple .txt files if the number of lines exceed 1000.

Thanks,

Comment: You can automate PowerPoint directly from Python (assuming you're running on Windows)  http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

You might explore using python-pptx to generate the PowerPoint file directly, avoiding the need to generate VBA code and do the copy pasting bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've checked out python-pptx, but I found some administrative problems with implementing it in our computer system. Thus I'm trying to find any other way that uses only barebone python.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a more elegant way of doing this? E.g. (1) is there a specific file extension which is recognized by Windows to be executed as ppt macro, so my users can double click the icon and it just executes the PPT?

No.

> > (2) or is there a way to use python to invoke PPT to run the macro? I can then just save the actual presentation.

See other comments regarding using python.  Or look into using VBScript instead of VBA.  VBScript can be launched from the command line and can automate PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks. VBScript seems like an interesting alternative. I'll take a look into it.